# Is it possible to access Ruby EventMachine Channels from Thin/Rack/Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, eventmachine, thin

I'm looking to build a simple, RESTful notification system for an internal project leveraging Sinatra. I've used EventMachine channels in the past to subscribe/publish to events, but in all my previous cases I was using EventMachine directly.

Does anyone know if it's possible to create, subscribe, and publish to EventMachine channels (running in Thin) from a Sinatra application, or even from some Rack middleware for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [async_sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra).

Basically, to make it possible to use EventMachine when running in Thin you need to make it aware that you want to serve requests asynchronously. The Rack protocol is synchronous by design, and Thin expects a request to be done when the handler returns. There are ways to make Thin aware that you want to handle the request asynchronously (see [think_async](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin_async) for an example how), and [async_sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra) makes it very easy.

Comment: Hmmm... so I don't need to serve requests asynchronously as much as I just need a way to leverage EventMachine's Channel object. However, your answer has made it obvious to me that the EventMachine running in Thin is available to Rack applications simply by referencing EM as one usually would.

As such, you've answered my question. Thanks Theo!

Comment: I assumed you wanted to use Channels to communicate within your application. For example while handling a request you want to publish to a channel, and wait for a reply on another channel, or perhaps you want to pop off a queue. These are asynchronous actions, and you must serve your requests asynchronously to handle them. If you, for example, ran `queue.pop { |msg| ... }` your request would already have been sent at the time the callback/block was called.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't necessarily explain what I was trying to accomplish very well. Essentially, I want to provide a RESTful interface for creating, pushing to, and registering with channels to support notification of other web servers outside of my application. In the end, I want one client to be able to push a notification to a channel and have all the web servers registered with said channel notified via a separate HTTP request defined in the queue.pop block.

Answer (score 1):

Bryan,
You can use the em-http-request library (https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request), this will allow you to reference a specific EventMachine application running on either A. the same server, B. a different server, or C. wherever you want really.

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http-request'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'thin'

class ServerClass < EventMachine::Connection
  def initialize(*args)
    # ruby singleton - store channel data in global hash
    ($channels ||= [])
  end

  def post_init
    puts "initialized"
    $cb.call("initialized");
  end

  def receive_data(data)
    # got information from client connection
  end

  def channel_send(msg,channel)
    $channels[channel].send_data(msg)
  end

  def channels_send(msg)
    $channels.each{|channel| channel.send_data(msg)}
  end

  def unbind
    # puts user left
  end

end

EventMachine.run do
  $cb = EM.callback {|msg| puts msg #do something creative}
  $ems = EventMachine::start_server('0.0.0.0',ServerClass,args)

  class App < Sinatra::Base
    set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'

    get '/' do
      erb :index          
    end

  end

  App.run!({:port => 3000})

end
```

Above is a basic wireframe. Depending on how you want to go about sending data, you can use WebSockets (em-websocket) and bind each user on login (have to add a login system), or you can use this for whatever. As long as you have a global reference to the Eventmachine Object (connection, websocket, channel) you can pass messages from within your application.

BTW - It is optional to add the EventMachine.run do;....end loop, since Thin will do this anyways. It helps to know how it works though.

Good Luck